# Search for file names using a text list

Tags: python

I am currently trying to search for a list of missing attachments that are scattered throughout our file share server.I have a txt file with a list of filenames I would like to find. Ideally at some point I would like to copy the file to another location when found. At this moment it doesn't seem to be working, because it returns no results and I have verified the files exist.

```
import os

source = open("Test.txt", "r")
dest = '//somewhere/somefolder'
path = '//somewhere/anotherfolder'

for line in source:
   print 'Searching . . .'
   print line
     for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):

       for name in files:

         if name in line:
            # shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, name), dest)
            print 'Found!'
            print path, name

print 'Done';
```

Comment: wouldn't you also need to do `source.read()`? At least in Py 2 that is a thing

Comment: Please fix the indentation. As it currently stands the code doesn't even run, because there is an unexpected indent between `print line` and `for root, dirs, files …`.

Comment: @patrick no, `for x in some_file.read()` would iterate over characters in the file. `for x in some_file` iterates over the lines.

Comment: @AdamSmith I stand corrected, thanks for pointing it out. Looks like my brain is still on vacation.

Comment: @PeterWood This won't cause the behavior here (`"foo" in "some line with a foo in it\n"` doesn't need to be stripped)

Comment: So I actually got this to work removing the name.lower and just using name.

Comment: If my list of filenames has the path included, is there a way to ignore the path and only search for the filename? (ex. //somewhere/anotherfolder/filename.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> **Question/Comment**:  is there a way to ignore the path and only search for the filename?

For instance:

```
import os

fpath = "//somewhere/anotherfolder/filename.pdf"
fname = os.path.basename(fpath)

print('fname=%s' % fname)
```

> **Output**:
>   fname=filename.pdf